# Dyalog APL language bar is missing

Tags: windows, apl, dyalog

I have just installed Dyalog APL and I can't see language bar above as well as other bars. No prior configuration was done. OS is Windows 7. 
Here you can see my window and normal look of it. 
[Normal look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pStp.png)
[My window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLCOG.jpg)
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dasha,welcome to StackOverflow :-)  It seems the session-file is missing or misconfigured - which seems surprising after a new installation. Did you move any files or have you fiddled with any of the settings? Can you pls. paste & execute this: `+2 ⎕nq'.' 'GetEnvironment' 'session_file'` - and pls. check if the file that is shown does exist on your machine and where you actually find .DSE on your machine...

Comment: Great you have asked this! I teach Dyalog APL to students and this problem regularly happens in my class!

Comment: It is surprising to hear this happens regularly. In this case Dyalog should know about it. Alex, did you ever get in touch with support@dyalog.com about it?

Comment: Just a question: did you "install" Dyalog by running the installer or did you copy the directory and .exe? If you ran the installer, was it under the same account you were using when the bar was missing?

Comment: No, I did not contact support of Dyalog because I was not able to reproduce the issue on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the 
BUILD_SESSION 'UK':

1)  Session->Save As and please save the session file somewhere on your system.  Anywhere you like.

As an example, you could make a folder c:\dyalog\ and save it in there.

2)   In Options|Configure|Session, look at the setting for Session file.

Change it to reflect where it really is.

So, following the example, it could be:
c:\dyalog\def_uk.dse

This should solve the issue and you should get a complete session every time you start Dyalog.

Regards,

Vince

Answer (score 2):

Dasha, Alexandar and MBaas,

MBaas is asking the right questions.

I've written a FAQ entry about what to do when this happens.

http://www.dyalog.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=480

Please contact me at Dyalog Support and let me know if this does or does not help you and what happened when you tried the steps.

Regards,

Vince

Comment: Thanks Vince, for coming over. I hope this solves the problem :-)

Comment: Hi Alexander, If you or your students experience this again, please let us know what setting is not working or what you do to correct this.

Comment: Wow! It works, thanks! I downloaded session file using this command " )load buildse BUILD_SESSION 'UK'  " then language bar and others appeared!)

Comment: Dasha, would you then please accept Vince's answer (click the checkmark on the left side), so that the issue is closed...

Comment: Yep, sure) Thanks :)